# NUGET restore package without Folder?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Is there an option to restore a NuGet package the the exact path defined in `repositoryPath`, ignoring any Package ID?

When restoring in Visual Studio 2017\2015 I get the path ..\Bin\PackageID.
I want the files to restored to ..\bin.

My package contains no folders inside, only the files.

- I use sample solution with no previous NuGet packages.
- Files are restored to the correct folder (..\bin\ but have the PagackgeID as added folder).

My Nuget.config

```
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="../Bin" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

My PackageCode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Bint</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title></title>
    <authors>admin</authors>
    <owners>admin</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My package description.</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework2.0" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework3.5" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETPortable0.0-Profile259" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETPortable0.0-Profile328" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.0" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.3" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Im sorry there was an answer here ,it is now deleted maybe i did it by mistake , if so please repost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you use `PackageReference`, it's mean you can't use `repositoryPath`.

From [nuget.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section):

> `repositoryPath` apply only to projects using `packages.config`.

---

> I want the files to restored to ..\bin\

You can use `RestorePackagesPath` property for specify restore packages folder, but folder structure with `PackageIdentity` will save. I think to change this behavior isn't possible, anyway documentation about this I didn't saw.

From [NuGet settings in MSBuild](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild#project-properties):

> Path to the user packages folder. All downloaded packages are
>   extracted here. Equivalent to `--packages` in `dotnet restore`.

Comment: any change i make still result in creation of a folder in the name of the package ID

Comment: @galsi, as I said `I think change this behavior isn't possible, anyway documentation about this I didn't saw.`. With help this NuGet is searching suitable package.

Comment: @galsi, similar approach used for packaging libraries, when used `nuget pack` command. `NuGet` finds by a package identity a folder with same name, then finds package with certain version. `PackageIdentity -> PackageIdentity + PackageVersion`. But I can be wrong.

Comment: Thanks,is there a way to copy the extracted content to different folder using the Nuget.config?

Comment: @galsi, no. Nuget.config only for packages.config style reference. For PackageReference see link that I sent above.